# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'CompanyName' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am with a problem that I can't solve. This "Caused by: db.DbException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'CompanyName' at row 1" keeps appearing to me. I will post the codes for a better understading.

```
public class CompanyFormController implements Initializable {

        private Company entity;
        private CompanyService service;

        @FXML private TextField txtCompanyName;

        @FXML private TextField txtCeoName;

        @FXML private TextField txtMobile;

        @FXML private TextField txtCountryMobileCode;

        @FXML private TextField txtEmail;

        @FXML private Label labelEmailError;

        @FXML private ComboBox<String> comboboxCountry;

        @FXML private DatePicker datepickerFoundationDate;

        @FXML private TextField txtWebsite;

        @FXML private ComboBox<String> comboboxIndustry;

        @FXML private ChoiceBox<String> choiceboxGrossSales;

        @FXML private Button btUploadCompanyName;

        @FXML private Button btSave;

        @FXML
        public void onBtSaveAction() {

            CompanyDaoJDBC jdbcDao = new CompanyDaoJDBC(DB.getConnection());
            jdbcDao.insert(new Company(1, String.valueOf(txtCompanyName), String.valueOf(txtCeoName), String.valueOf(txtCountryMobileCode) + String.valueOf(txtMobile), String.valueOf(txtEmail), String.valueOf(comboboxCountry), String.valueOf(datepickerFoundationDate), String.valueOf(txtWebsite), String.valueOf(comboboxIndustry), String.valueOf(choiceboxGrossSales)));
        }
```

The question here is When I code like this above appears the erros but When put "" on the value inside the String.valueOf It works fine and my Database save the values.

And this is where the method insert is:

```
@Override
public void insert(Company obj) {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try {
        st = conn.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO company " +
            "(Id, CompanyName, CeoName, PhoneNumber, Email, Country, FoundationDate, Website, Industry, GrossSales) " +
            "VALUES " +
            "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        st.setInt(1, obj.getId());
        st.setString(2, obj.getCompanyName());
        st.setString(3, obj.getCeoName());
        st.setString(4, obj.getPhoneNumber());
        st.setString(5, obj.getEmail());
        st.setString(6, obj.getCountry());
        st.setString(7, obj.getFoundationDate());
        st.setString(8, obj.getWebsite());
        st.setString(9, obj.getIndustry());
        st.setString(10, obj.getGrossSales());

        int rowsAffected = st.executeUpdate();

        if (rowsAffected > 0) {
            ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                obj.setId(id);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new DbException("Unexpected error! No rows affected!");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DbException(e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally {
        DB.closeStatement(st);
    }
}
```

I will let you my Company Class:

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer id;
private String companyName;
private String ceoName;
private String phoneNumber;
private String email;
private String country;
private String foundationDate;
private String website;
private String industry;
private String grossSales;

public Company() {
}

public Company(Integer id, String companyName, String ceoName, String phoneNumber, String email, String country,
        String foundationDate, String website, String industry, String grossSales) {
    this.id = id;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.ceoName = ceoName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.email = email;
    this.country = country;
    this.foundationDate = foundationDate;
    this.website = website;
    this.industry = industry;
    this.grossSales = grossSales;
}
```

And this is MySQL table info:

Table: company

Columns:

Id int AI PK

CompanyName varchar(60)

CeoName varchar(60)

PhoneNumber varchar(60)

Email varchar(100)

Country varchar(60)

FoundationDate varchar(30)

Website varchar(80)

Industry varchar(40)

GrossSales varchar(120)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set data that is bigger that allowed. Try using another text data type, or increasing the size allowed.

Comment: try using varchar(65535) and see if works. if it does, size is the problem, thats what the exception is telling.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what I did wrong, I didn't "convert" the TextField into String.

Solution:

```
jdbcDao.insert(new Company(1, txtCompanyName.getText(), txtCeoName.getText(), txtCountryMobileCode.getText() + txtMobile.getText(), txtEmail.getText(),  comboboxCountry.getValue(), datepickerFoundationDate.getValue().toString(), txtWebsite.getText(), comboboxIndustry.getValue(), choiceboxGrossSales.getValue()));
```

Do you know how do I put my id (is the number '1') automatic?
 because I don't want to put a number on that field. In MYSQL the id field is Auto Increment.